# Nodejs extra-security actions necessary if frontend uses SSL?

Tags: node.js, security, ssl, action, frontend

I developed a website that will be hosted on a webhosting server with dedicated IP in order to be able to use SSL (https). 
This website makes some calls to a node.js app running on a VPS i am hiring. In this VPS i have some sensible data (database) and in the app i have a sensible user and password. I would like to know if the frontend uses SSL is enough to secure my VPS and app.js, or if there are some other actions i should perform.

Also i would be grateful if you can advise which is the best solution to hire: Dedicated IP WebHosting(frontend) + VPS (backend) Versus VPS (backedn and frontend). It's my first website and I need some experienced advices.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

If Node.js will be running with ssl certificate, then please use passphrase for ssl certificate that will be asked if you run node.js server. This will provide additional security.
Also, you can request for client certificate and reject unauthorized that provide additional layer of security and prevent from man-in-middle attack.